# IE showing syntax errors on function

Tags: javascript

So once again, IE is the ultimate culprit when it comes to my JavaScript not working and it's showing a 'Syntax error' when I load the page on IE using BrowserStack.

Firefox/Chrome show no errors and the functionality works.

**Here is what I had at first**:

```
function get_states() {
    let data_states =  contactFormID.getAttribute('data-states').match(/\w{1,}/g);
    data_states.forEach( (state,i) => states[i] = state);
}
```

**I converted it to ES2015 using Babeljs.io with no luck**:

```
function get_states() {
    var data_states = contactFormID.getAttribute('data-states').match(/\w{1,}/g);
    data_states.forEach(function (state, i) {
        return states[i] = state;
    });
}
```

**Here is the error**:

[image]

[image]

Does IE not support forEach? I've even added the following script tag using polyfill: `<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2Cdefault%2Ces5%2Ces6%2Ces2016%2CArray.prototype.forEach"></script>` with no luck.

Comment: Which IE version are you talking about?

Comment: No, [IE doesn't support `forEach`](https://caniuse.com/#search=foreach). That polyfill URL should be fixed I guess, since it links to [an empty script](https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2Cdefault%2Ces5%2Ces6%2Ces2016%2CArray.prototype.forEach)

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, IE 11

Comment: @ChrisG, I guess it's the polyfill generator on that link because I just tried a new link and it's returning an empty one also. Do you know any other polyfill CDN's?

Comment: You can try adding the `always` flag.

Comment: That has to be a mistake in caniuse, IE definitely supports `Array.forEach`. In the very similar question you've asked yesterfay, I told you to not convert ES2015, if you want to support IE, convert to ES5 instead.

Comment: Hi @Teemu, sorry I didn't see a option on babeljs.io for ES5 so I thought ES2015 and ES5 we're the same. I'll make that change now.

Comment: ES2015 === ES6.

Comment: @Teemu, ahh - Although it sounds confusing, I'll have to remember that.

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new/javascript-version-information?redirectedfrom=MSDN) says `forEach` is supported since IE9. If you need to support older IES, you've to convert to ES3, and a lot of the DOM stuff need polyfills.

Comment: Ah, I was a bit hasty when I looked at the caniuse page Chris G has linked. The page was about `NodeList.forEach`, and that is really not supported in any version of IE. `match`, however, returns a regular array ...

Comment: Inside your function, what is `states[i]` and in it, `i`? I cannot see a variable being defined, named that. I hope you're not working on global variables. Also I don't see any line of code increase `i` so all your loop iterations keep overwriting the same array entry. That would be **really** bad.

Comment: @connexo, I have `var states = [];` setup.

Comment: As mentioned, that is **really bad coding**. ***Never* use global variables.** Instead, pass the array you want to modify as an argument to your function.

Comment: @connexo `i` is declared in the arguments of `forEach`, and it represents the current index of the iteration round (I'm sure you knew that already, just not have noticed it here).

Comment: @Teemu Good spot, ofc.

Comment: IE doesn't support ES2015, try ES5 or ES3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by including a forEach polyfill for all the forEach actions.

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```